# How to force SSO on a login page WSO2

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I have configured SAML Web SSO for my application.

Today I came across the following scenario:

1. User tries to access a page of a Service Provider (SP) who is not authenticated and is redirected to the SAML login page of WSO2 to enter his credentials using Local Basic Authenticator.
2. User opens a second tab with the same Service Provider before authenticating on the first tab.
3. User logs in successfully on any of the two tabs
4. Refreshing the tab that is still open on the Login page doesn't login the user, instead displays the login form.

From the `http_access_logs` I am seeing the following:

When the user tries to authenticate:

```
[20/Feb/2020:17:02:39 +0000] GET /samlsso?tenantDomain=domain.com&SAMLRequest=abcdef.....&RelayState=myRelayState HTTP/1.1 302 - - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36 0.018
[20/Feb/2020:17:02:39 +0000] GET /authenticationendpoint/login.do?RelayState=myRelayState&.........parameters_ommited..... HTTP/1.1 200 2953 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36 0.003
[20/Feb/2020:17:02:40 +0000] GET /logincontext?sessionDataKey=e3a4e5c3-60dd-4466-8586-9dae01a4a8d8&.....parameters_ommited.... Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36 0.000
```

This is the flow of the requests when directed from the SP.

However when the user is refreshing the login page, even when he has authenticated on another tab, only the latter two requests are received.

```
[20/Feb/2020:17:14:26 +0000] GET /authenticationendpoint/login.do?RelayState=myRelayState&.....parameters_ommited..... Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36 0.004
[20/Feb/2020:17:14:27 +0000] GET /logincontext?sessionDataKey=e3a4e5c3-60dd-4466-8586-9dae01a4a8d8&.....parameters_ommited...... Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36 0.007
```

From my understanding the reason is that the user is not directed to the `/samlsso` on refresh, it asks for the login form directly.

Is the expected functionality that I would like something that the WSO2 server can handle, and if so how?

Comment: What is the IS version you are using? IMO this is not the expected behaviour. If you want you can check the latest doc IS and how their SSO sample works https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/next/get-started/quick-start-guide/#configuring-sso-with-saml2.

Comment: @Inthirakumaaran IS 5.9.0, maybe you are right, wrong use of wording. I meant to say that's my desired behaviour. I haven't seen anything related to that on the docs but I will give it a retry!

Comment: It is the expected behavior. As you already said, on second tab user is asking for login page which is deployed as a seperate web application, and he is getting the same, so nothing wrong here. If user will try to access any page of SP, he will not see any login page as the session has been created already